# Printed the code insufficient number of times

Tags: python, pycharm

so I am a total beginner in programming and and I use Pycharm and when i put the following:

```
ListName = "hello world"
for i in ListName:
    print(ListName)
```

code gave me "hello world" but repeated it 11 times, and when i tried the same with another variable, it got repeated 13 times, i do not know if its a setting problem because when i tried simple

`print("hello world")`
it was the usual response. If someone is familiar with Pycharm, please enlighten me as your newbie junior

Comment: Instead of `print(ListName)`. Try `print(i)`. You will see.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PyCharm - this is fundamental Python. I suggest https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 0):

it should not be depended on the variable you using only on the value of it. check out below codes how does they run.

```
ListName = "hello world"
count = 0
for i in ListName:
   count = count+1
   print(ListName,count)

x = "Hello world"
count = 0
for i in x:
   count = count+1
   print(i,count)
```

Comment: i got hello world 1
hello world 2
hello world 3
hello world 4
hello world 5
hello world 6
hello world 7
hello world 8
hello world 9
hello world 10
hello world 11

Answer (score 0):

When you type `for i ListName:`, python treats the string that `ListName` is holding as an iterable. It iterates through the string letter by letter. The variable `i` will store the corresponding letter at each iteration. However, the line `print(listName)` does not reference the variable `i` which is holding a single letter. Instead it simply prints the entire string stored in `listName` at each iteration. And since there are 11 characters in the string "hello world", the loop runs 11 times.

As pointed out in the comment, it will help you to understand what is going on if you run:

```
for i in listName:
    print(i)
```